E: Unable to locate package libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev
I'm trying to install libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev as some app need it. However I keep getting the error message. I did try to add the repository by sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wxwidgets/libwxgtk3.0-gtk3  though. I'm using Ubuntu 24.04
sudo apt install build-essential libgtk-3-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev'


this package doesn't exist in noble but exists in jammy https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev

The package you're looking for is part of the wxwidgets3.0 source package.  This was removed from Ubuntu repositories on March 15, 2023 with the following reason:

(From Debian) ROM; Unmaintained; replaced by wxwidgets3.2; Debian bug #1032585

From the listed Debian Bug:

RM: wxwidgets3.0 -- ROM; Unmaintained; replaced by wxwidgets3.2

wxwidgets3.0 is unmaintained, and was removed from Debian because it was superseded and replaced by wxwidgets3.2.  It was removed during the Lunar development cycle and is why it's not present in later releases.

Note that the PPA you indicated does not exist, therefore you will not be able to get updates through there.

You will need to have whoever develop these apps that need this to rewrite them against wxwidgets3.2.  Or find alternative applications.
You can attempt to install the newer version with libwxgtk3.2-dev - if your application does not run with that you need to wait for an update or find an alternative app.

Will the app not work under wxwidgets3.2? If it does, how do I install it? cause I'm getting the same error when installing wxwidgets3.2 as well

As Thomas Ward said, the wxwidget3.0 is abandoned, but 3.2 version will work with those app that is using 3.0 version therefore just need to
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libwxgtk3.2-dev

Note: This is tested on Ubuntu 24.04 Noble Release

Added those notes of what to install as part of my answer.  :D  (So you can mark it as accepted and mark the issue as solved)

yes, I see, can you always add sudo apt install libwxgtk3.2-dev to the answer? As it's more clear and helpful for ubuntu beginners
